# How to handle error in material-ui DataGrid?

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

i use material-ui dataGrid and one of props loading={false/true} get true or false. I need same props but for error handling, but props error always true. How can i handle error ?

```
<DataGrid
    className={classes.root}
    components={{
      LoadingOverlay: CustomLoadingOverlay,
      NoRowsOverlay: CustomNoRowsOverlay,
      ErrorOverlay: CustomErrorOverlay,
    }}
    loading={loading}
    rows={data}
    columns={columns}
    pageSize={10} 
  />
```

Answer (score 3):

You aren't setting the error prop. All you need to do is add the error prop like below and you should be good. Granted, you still need to handle the actual error.

```
<DataGrid
    className={classes.root}
    components={{
      LoadingOverlay: CustomLoadingOverlay,
      NoRowsOverlay: CustomNoRowsOverlay,
      ErrorOverlay: CustomErrorOverlay,
    }}
    loading={loading}
    error={error} {/* Here */}
    rows={data}
    columns={columns}
    pageSize={10} 
  />
```